# Picking Letters out of Words in TextBox C#2010 Express

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm currently programming on Hangman in C# and I want to create a multiplayer. With this multiplayer Button in the Menu are getting a new Form (Form4 in my Program) opened where Player 1 have to write the word in. When he did that he can go on in the final game. Now the Problem(s):

1. Problem
   I'm a German and we have Ä,Ö,Ü and ß as letters, but i want to switch them in AE, OE, UE and SS when they are gonna get written. Now, I did this with changing the textBox1_TextChanged into Key Down. I did this in the Form itself and in the Form4.Designer.cs

   `private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)`

and in the Designer.cs

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
```

Now the Problem (maybe obvious for you):

`Error  1   "Hangman_RUEL.Form4" has no definition of "textBox1_TextChanged", and it could not get a "textBox1_TextChanged", that accept "Hangman_RUEL.Form4" (Missing Using-Direktive or Assembly?)    F:\Hangman\Hangman RUEL\Hangman RUEL\Form4.Designer.cs  77  71  Hangman RUEL`

*may not be the original Error code in English because I translated it.

2. Problem
   How can I read out the letters from a Word in a TextBox? I didn't find anything good on the internet so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?:

```
string input = someTextBox.Text;
```

and

`someTextBox.OnKeyDown += (o, a) => { some code you want to add... };`

Comment: `string s = textBox1.Text.Trim();` This is what i have but the second one isnt working better :(